# ExtJS Classic: When animating x/y/width/height of a window, the title is not ending at the final position specified

Tags: javascript, animation, extjs, extjs7

Using ExtJS Classic 7.3.0

Trying to animate the window while it is showing, but the title of the window is not ending up at the specifications in 'TO' config. Fiddle is here: [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3do8)

If you try to drag the window by clicking on the "blue title", you will see the entire title how it should be, but thats it.

Anyone know if I need to specify something else here?

Answer (score 0):

I tinkered with it a bit and found that it worked if you set the width property on the window:

```js
width: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width / 2,
```

Full code:

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
            id: 'win',
            title: "Window",
            width: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width / 2,
            html: "<h1>Hello</h1> ",
            listeners: {
                show: function (win) {
                    var el = win.getEl();
                    var size = Ext.getBody().getViewSize();
                    el.animate({
                        from: {
                        opacity: 0,
                        width: 0,
                        height: 0,
                        x: size.width/2,
                        y: size.height/2
                    },
                    to: {
                        opacity: 100,
                        width: size.width/2,
                        height: size.height/2,
                        x: size.width/4,
                        y: size.height/4
                    },
                    
                    });
                },
                beforeclose: function (win) {
                    if (!win.shouldClose) {
                        win.getEl().fadeOut({
                            duration: 2000,
                            callback: function () {
                                win.shouldClose = true;
                                win.close();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return win.shouldClose ? true : false;
                }
            }
        }).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: That does work. Seems like a workaround, but I’ll use it for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
width: '50%'
```

also seems to work.

Comment: @PaulFarry I don't see any link here